# Pandas variance over rolling groups

Tags: python, pandas, group-by, pandas-groupby, rolling-computation

I have a large df at hand that looks like the following example, but with many more PERMNOs per day.I would like to apply a rolling two-period variance of daily returns for each PERMNO.

I know how to do this for each single period:

```
df['Monthly Variance'] = df.groupby(['PERMNO', 'Period'])['RET'].var()
```

But how do I do this for rolling periods? E.g. every row with period 2019-05 should include the variance of all daily returns included in 2019-05 and 2019-04.

Data:

```
    date        Period  PERMNO  RET         SPREAD
0   2019-03-19  2019-03 93436   -0.007496   0.037349
1   2019-03-29  2019-03 93436   0.004450    0.020619
2   2019-04-10  2019-04 93436   0.013771    0.020109
3   2019-04-23  2019-04 93436   0.004377    0.038514
4   2019-05-03  2019-05 93436   0.044777    0.053883
5   2019-05-15  2019-05 93436   -0.001550   0.031920
6   2019-05-28  2019-05 93436   -0.010124   0.038062
7   2019-06-07  2019-06 93436   -0.007041   0.036093
8   2019-06-19  2019-06 93436   0.007520    0.030354
9   2019-07-01  2019-07 93436   0.016602    0.030137
10  2019-07-12  2019-07 93436   0.027158    0.023654
11  2019-07-24  2019-07 93436   0.018104    0.030640
12  2019-08-05  2019-08 93436   -0.025689   0.024769
13  2019-08-15  2019-08 93436   -0.018122   0.047317
14  2019-08-27  2019-08 93436   -0.004279   0.031929
15  2019-09-09  2019-09 93436   0.019081    0.019762
16  2019-09-19  2019-09 93436   0.012773    0.012661
17  2019-10-01  2019-10 93436   0.015859    0.028520
18  2019-10-11  2019-10 93436   0.012871    0.017301
19  2019-10-23  2019-10 93436   -0.003521   0.019057
20  2019-11-04  2019-11 93436   0.013278    0.041001
21  2019-11-14  2019-11 93436   0.009361    0.031874
22  2019-11-26  2019-11 93436   -0.022061   0.025680
23  2019-12-09  2019-12 93436   0.010837    0.027964
24  2019-12-19  2019-12 93436   0.027699    0.026103

import pandas as pd
from pandas import Timestamp

d = {'date': {0: Timestamp('2019-03-19 00:00:00'),
    1: Timestamp('2019-03-29 00:00:00'),
    2: Timestamp('2019-04-10 00:00:00'),
    3: Timestamp('2019-04-23 00:00:00'),
    4: Timestamp('2019-05-03 00:00:00'),
    5: Timestamp('2019-05-15 00:00:00'),
    6: Timestamp('2019-05-28 00:00:00'),
    7: Timestamp('2019-06-07 00:00:00'),
    8: Timestamp('2019-06-19 00:00:00'),
    9: Timestamp('2019-07-01 00:00:00'),
    10: Timestamp('2019-07-12 00:00:00'),
    11: Timestamp('2019-07-24 00:00:00'),
    12: Timestamp('2019-08-05 00:00:00'),
    13: Timestamp('2019-08-15 00:00:00'),
    14: Timestamp('2019-08-27 00:00:00'),
    15: Timestamp('2019-09-09 00:00:00'),
    16: Timestamp('2019-09-19 00:00:00'),
    17: Timestamp('2019-10-01 00:00:00'),
    18: Timestamp('2019-10-11 00:00:00'),
    19: Timestamp('2019-10-23 00:00:00'),
    20: Timestamp('2019-11-04 00:00:00'),
    21: Timestamp('2019-11-14 00:00:00'),
    22: Timestamp('2019-11-26 00:00:00'),
    23: Timestamp('2019-12-09 00:00:00'),
    24: Timestamp('2019-12-19 00:00:00')},
    'Period': {0: Period('2019-03', 'M'),
    1: Period('2019-03', 'M'),
    2: Period('2019-04', 'M'),
    3: Period('2019-04', 'M'),
    4: Period('2019-05', 'M'),
    5: Period('2019-05', 'M'),
    6: Period('2019-05', 'M'),
    7: Period('2019-06', 'M'),
    8: Period('2019-06', 'M'),
    9: Period('2019-07', 'M'),
    10: Period('2019-07', 'M'),
    11: Period('2019-07', 'M'),
    12: Period('2019-08', 'M'),
    13: Period('2019-08', 'M'),
    14: Period('2019-08', 'M'),
    15: Period('2019-09', 'M'),
    16: Period('2019-09', 'M'),
    17: Period('2019-10', 'M'),
    18: Period('2019-10', 'M'),
    19: Period('2019-10', 'M'),
    20: Period('2019-11', 'M'),
    21: Period('2019-11', 'M'),
    22: Period('2019-11', 'M'),
    23: Period('2019-12', 'M'),
    24: Period('2019-12', 'M')},
    'PERMNO': {0: 93436,
    1: 93436,
    2: 93436,
    3: 93436,
    4: 93436,
    5: 93436,
    6: 93436,
    7: 93436,
    8: 93436,
    9: 93436,
    10: 93436,
    11: 93436,
    12: 93436,
    13: 93436,
    14: 93436,
    15: 93436,
    16: 93436,
    17: 93436,
    18: 93436,
    19: 93436,
    20: 93436,
    21: 93436,
    22: 93436,
    23: 93436,
    24: 93436},
    'RET': {0: -0.007496,
    1: 0.00445,
    2: 0.013771,
    3: 0.004377,
    4: 0.044777,
    5: -0.00155,
    6: -0.010124,
    7: -0.007041,
    8: 0.00752,
    9: 0.016602,
    10: 0.027158,
    11: 0.018104,
    12: -0.025689,
    13: -0.018122,
    14: -0.004279,
    15: 0.019081,
    16: 0.012773,
    17: 0.015859,
    18: 0.012871,
    19: -0.003521,
    20: 0.013278,
    21: 0.009361,
    22: -0.022061,
    23: 0.010837,
    24: 0.027699},
    'SPREAD': {0: 0.03734912462419806,
    1: 0.02061930783242268,
    2: 0.02010868822370299,
    3: 0.03851421309872922,
    4: 0.053883031997904014,
    5: 0.031920088790233066,
    6: 0.038062228476857696,
    7: 0.03609261156529571,
    8: 0.030353750113091504,
    9: 0.030137440339402532,
    10: 0.02365353870704016,
    11: 0.030639552742658626,
    12: 0.024769351113690646,
    13: 0.04731741904986996,
    14: 0.031929443946611374,
    15: 0.019761767656938437,
    16: 0.012661329848064019,
    17: 0.028520051854639707,
    18: 0.017300757667841702,
    19: 0.01905709094660478,
    20: 0.04100106573753255,
    21: 0.03187425271937228,
    22: 0.025680188759395033,
    23: 0.027963531931584486,
    24: 0.026103430012610333}}
    
df = pd.DataFrame(d)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use pandas [resampling](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.resample.html) it works.  Note you need to define a column that meets requirements for resampling.  This effectively makes **Period** column redundant.   You can also look into `rollup()` as well.  I've done an example of this as well.

```
df["ts"] = pd.to_datetime(df.date, unit="ms", utc=True)
df["Monthly Variance"] = df.groupby(["PERMNO"]).resample("M", on="ts")["RET"].transform("var")
df["Bi-Monthly Variance"] = df.groupby(["PERMNO"]).resample("2M", on="ts")["RET"].transform("var")
df["Quarterly Variance"] = df.groupby(["PERMNO"]).resample("Q", on="ts")["RET"].transform("var")
df["Yearly Variance"] = df.groupby(["PERMNO"]).resample("Y", on="ts")["RET"].transform("var")
df["Rolling Variance"] = df.rolling(10,on="ts")["RET"].var()
```

**Only calculate latest data rather than whole data frame**

```
dfsub = df[df["ts"]>=pd.to_datetime(Timestamp('2019-08-01 00:00:00'), unit="ms", utc=True)].copy()
df.loc[dfsub.index,"Bi-Monthly Variance"] = 0
df.loc[dfsub.index,"Bi-Monthly Variance"] = df.loc[dfsub.index,].groupby(["PERMNO"]).resample("2M", on="ts").transform("var")["RET"]
```

```
    date        Period  PERMNO  RET         SPREAD      ts                       Monthly Variance   Bi-Monthly Variance Quarterly Variance  Yearly Variance Rolling Variance
0   2019-03-19  2019-03 93436   -0.007496   0.037349    2019-03-19 00:00:00+00:00   0.000071    0.000071    0.000071    0.000268    NaN
1   2019-03-29  2019-03 93436   0.004450    0.020619    2019-03-29 00:00:00+00:00   0.000071    0.000071    0.000071    0.000268    NaN
2   2019-04-10  2019-04 93436   0.013771    0.020109    2019-04-10 00:00:00+00:00   0.000044    0.000448    0.000340    0.000268    NaN
3   2019-04-23  2019-04 93436   0.004377    0.038514    2019-04-23 00:00:00+00:00   0.000044    0.000448    0.000340    0.000268    NaN
4   2019-05-03  2019-05 93436   0.044777    0.053883    2019-05-03 00:00:00+00:00   0.000872    0.000448    0.000340    0.000268    NaN
5   2019-05-15  2019-05 93436   -0.001550   0.031920    2019-05-15 00:00:00+00:00   0.000872    0.000448    0.000340    0.000268    NaN
6   2019-05-28  2019-05 93436   -0.010124   0.038062    2019-05-28 00:00:00+00:00   0.000872    0.000448    0.000340    0.000268    NaN
7   2019-06-07  2019-06 93436   -0.007041   0.036093    2019-06-07 00:00:00+00:00   0.000106    0.000167    0.000340    0.000268    NaN
8   2019-06-19  2019-06 93436   0.007520    0.030354    2019-06-19 00:00:00+00:00   0.000106    0.000167    0.000340    0.000268    NaN
9   2019-07-01  2019-07 93436   0.016602    0.030137    2019-07-01 00:00:00+00:00   0.000033    0.000167    0.000374    0.000268    0.000261
10  2019-07-12  2019-07 93436   0.027158    0.023654    2019-07-12 00:00:00+00:00   0.000033    0.000167    0.000374    0.000268    0.000273
11  2019-07-24  2019-07 93436   0.018104    0.030640    2019-07-24 00:00:00+00:00   0.000033    0.000167    0.000374    0.000268    0.000275
12  2019-08-05  2019-08 93436   -0.025689   0.024769    2019-08-05 00:00:00+00:00   0.000118    0.000370    0.000374    0.000268    0.000410
13  2019-08-15  2019-08 93436   -0.018122   0.047317    2019-08-15 00:00:00+00:00   0.000118    0.000370    0.000374    0.000268    0.000475
14  2019-08-27  2019-08 93436   -0.004279   0.031929    2019-08-27 00:00:00+00:00   0.000118    0.000370    0.000374    0.000268    0.000284
15  2019-09-09  2019-09 93436   0.019081    0.019762    2019-09-09 00:00:00+00:00   0.000020    0.000370    0.000374    0.000268    0.000318
16  2019-09-19  2019-09 93436   0.012773    0.012661    2019-09-19 00:00:00+00:00   0.000020    0.000370    0.000374    0.000268    0.000308
17  2019-10-01  2019-10 93436   0.015859    0.028520    2019-10-01 00:00:00+00:00   0.000109    0.000214    0.000221    0.000268    0.000301
18  2019-10-11  2019-10 93436   0.012871    0.017301    2019-10-11 00:00:00+00:00   0.000109    0.000214    0.000221    0.000268    0.000304
19  2019-10-23  2019-10 93436   -0.003521   0.019057    2019-10-23 00:00:00+00:00   0.000109    0.000214    0.000221    0.000268    0.000304
20  2019-11-04  2019-11 93436   0.013278    0.041001    2019-11-04 00:00:00+00:00   0.000375    0.000214    0.000221    0.000268    0.000256
21  2019-11-14  2019-11 93436   0.009361    0.031874    2019-11-14 00:00:00+00:00   0.000375    0.000214    0.000221    0.000268    0.000236
22  2019-11-26  2019-11 93436   -0.022061   0.025680    2019-11-26 00:00:00+00:00   0.000375    0.000214    0.000221    0.000268    0.000214
23  2019-12-09  2019-12 93436   0.010837    0.027964    2019-12-09 00:00:00+00:00   0.000142    0.000142    0.000221    0.000268    0.000159
24  2019-12-19  2019-12 93436   0.027699    0.026103    2019-12-19 00:00:00+00:00   0.000142    0.000142    0.000221    0.000268    0.000185
```

Comment: Ok, that is already helpful. The problem is, that this computes these variances for each day. I only need them at the end of every month (less computations for a large df). I see that Period really is redunant, how can I perform the Bi-monthly option only at a date that meets months end?

Comment: I've updated answer.  It's really no different - clearly you only have a need for *bi-monthly* I provided examples for other time periods.  Optimisation is just about only calc what you need.  Example just takes August as it's an even month number.  I've clearly not fully tested your use case.  The docs on pandas are pretty good when you get used to them

Comment: Maybe an obvious point - but you need all data for required calc not just month end,  then it's down to scheduling tasks appropriately - standard enterprise computing .... batch design.